# Eclipse and maven dependency during development

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependency-management

I do have own developed Java library (*MyLib*), which I later publish on private Maven repository and have it as Maven dependency in another webapp project (*MyWebapp*). If I have both projects - *MyLib* and *MyWebapp* at the same time opened in Eclipse - is there a way somehow to configure *MyWebapp* so, that local changes made to *MyLib* would be directly added to *MyWebapp* while building/deploying it? The issue is that during development it is not really comfortable always to make some changes in *MyLib*, make a build, deploy to Maven repository and then make a *MyWebapp* build, deploy it and only then I can see how the changes are affecting the webapp project...

I would like to reduce the overhead while developing and willing to see how changes are working out. Of course when it comes to real releases the above described flow does really make sense and works great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple "just tick this option" solution, unfortunately. You can chose between these options:

1. Convert `MyLib` into a Maven module and add it to the sources of `MyWebapp`. This, of course, will make it harder later to reuse the library alone.
2. Stop deploying the application. If you look at the classpath in Eclipse, m2e should have added the dependency as a project from the workspace (instead of depending on the JAR in the repository). If not: There is an option for this.

   The next step is to create another project which depends on Jetty and `MyWebapp`. Create a Java application in there (i.e. a file with `main()`) which creates a Jetty server and configure it to use the current classpath. That way, you can start the webapp just like any other Java application without deploying - Jetty will simply load classes from the classpath that m2e assembled.